# Has Stack Overflow been haiku-hacked?

Tags: support, spam, haiku, hacked

When for the first time
A new question I answer
This haiku appears:

> Little slab of meat
>   In a wash of clear jelly
>   Now I heat the pan

Such a message is
Very strange; is anyone
Seeing the same thing?

Have not seen again.
Came and went like the wind does!
Why I am so blessed?

Comment: You've just been with a haiku.

Comment: Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan

Comment: wtf is this??????

Comment: So you have a habit of answering questions more than once?

Comment: @random - quite often i'll edit my answers :)

Comment: Edits are not the same as posting a new answer to the same question.

Comment: This is pretty much awesome.

Comment: Maybe an easter egg.

Comment: Screenshot please... for posterity you see.  And um... *cough* hand-drawn circle around the haiku *caugh*.

Comment: I love that the whole post is a haiku now, lol

Comment: I'm glad someone appreciated the effort. (I'm not really happy with the final haiku, but it was the best I could muster with limited time.)

Comment: Was it just me who hadn't heard of Haiku before the new president of the EU council was [announced](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/belgium/6494387/Haiku-loving-Belgian-PM-Herman-Van-Rompuy-in-line-for-EU-presidency.html)?

Comment: I got this too :( ... I'm not a spam
Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan

Comment: As I've written at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144708/foo/#comment412764_144708: A spambot could parse the message, find words like "spam", "detected", "filter", or "triggered", and use them to determine whether it has triggered a spam filter and act accordingly. The haiku is itself meant to be a Turing test, so that bots don't know they triggered a spam filter.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The implementors of these sites have come up with a set of heuristics that attempt to detect spamming. I don't know exactly what they are, and if I did, I don't think they would be happy with me for typing them here. However, from my own observation, I've concluded that the site shows a Spam Haiku when the heuristics go off. Human beings scratch their heads, retry, and succeed. Actual robot spam devices are stymied. I imagine that if you thought a bit about what sorts of time and content patterns might be associated with automated spam, you could figure out why you got to read one.

Comment: +1 for an explanation, finally: *the site shows a Spam Haiku when the heuristics go off*

Comment: A +1 from me too.

Answer (score 19):

Spam haiku, baffling
[Five](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32789/what-is-this-spam-haiku-nonsense-all-about), yet [most](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32712/overactive-spam-ku) [still](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32850/weird-page-while-submitting-answers-might-be-the-slow-internet-connection-clos) [stuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32796/strange-haiki-after-posting-message-closed)
FAQ weeps for update.

Tastes like ham, sorta
But clogs up my aorta
Pig rigor morta

A half-eaten slice.
Ants swarm the cold, greasy plate.
A suicide note.

Comment: I just sent my great aunt a Christmas thank-you card composed entirely of haikus. I wonder if she'll appreciate it.

Comment: She definitely will!

Comment: Well, I just heard back from her. She liked it but also sent me a page of instruction on the proper use of imagery in haikus (though she did admit that thank-you haikus are necessarily somewhat image-limited). **Pro tip:** *Don't write poetry for an ex-English teacher unless you're prepared to deal with the consequences.*

Comment: @mmyers glad to know she liked it!

Answer (score 6):

What are the clear parts?
My mind reels, thoughts turn to hooves.
I'd best just eat it.

Answer (score 3):

I vaguely remember something about this clever poetry from a podcast/blog/tweet or somewhere. It's displayed to make the user slow down and think for a bit, when they are doing something ignorant or obnoxious. Like posting the same (spammy) question multiple times in a row, perhaps?

Comment: Sounds like this could work .... on some other planet.

Answer (score 2):

The haiku is trying to tell you something.

(edit: without a repro, there's no help that can be provided. If you give us repro steps we all can follow, I can tell you more.)

Comment: That they're routing the site through Hawaii?

Comment: I hope the message the haiku is trying to get across isn't very important.

Comment: @Jeff: Well if you're not worried then what the heck are of the rest of us concerned about! :) I welcome our new exception handling strings that are much more engaging than archaic error codes.

Answer (score 1):

No, Stack Overflow is not "hacked"; it's a Spam Haiku.

Comment: It can be found in the top 10 spam haikus http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA342CA342&q=spam+haikus&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq= but I don't think this leads to the conclusion that SO has not been hacked - in fact the opposite because there's no reason (business, technical, otherwise) that SO should show a spam haiku!

Answer (score 1):

Oh tin of pink meat / I ponder what you may be / Snout or ear or feet?

That's the latest :P

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it.  Very odd, I went back and resubmitted.

Comment: Does it only happen when posting an answer on SO? I haven't done that in a couple of days, so I could have missed it.

Comment: Pretty sure it was for an answer on SO, but it's either that or for an answer on meta...