# Overactive spam-ku

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam, haiku

Hey, I got the spam haiku!

I don't know what the criteria is; I got it after struggling to post from a dodgy connection on the train; after reconnecting, I hit "post" and got the haiku:

> Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan

The same post worked fine later.

Come on Jeff, take some pity on feeble connections!

---

Repro steps:

- prepare an answer in the "answer" box below
- simlulate crappy network (unplug cable, turn off wireless, etc)
- click the button to post it
- wait for it to fail
- click back
- reconnect network
- for me (Chrome) my answer is still there
- click the button to post it

> Grotesque pinkish mass / In a blue can on a shelf / Quivering alone

Comment: Yep, I keep getting this from 3G as well :(

Comment: That spamku is wrong. It's not grotesque. It's an enjoyable block of luncheon meat. Now in turkey flavour.

Comment: I'm also getting this tethering my G1 to my computer. (edge == yuck)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-bydesign] unless you have consistent repro steps

Disconnecting internet is considered a repro? Really? Man, I am going to open some MAJOR bugs against some websites tomorrow!!

I can't disclose the rules of our spam detection in public for what I hope are obvious reasons. Suffice it to say that a completely failed "I got no internet, man" HTTP post, followed by another HTTP post, trips enough of them.

edit: ah, I finally found the bug. Something that should have only applied to anonymous users was kicking in for registered users.

Comment: Adding repro steps

Comment: Did you manage to repro?

Comment: how do I "disconnect internet" to localhost? :)

Comment: Fair enough - but "disconnecting internet" is not entirely unexpected in an occasionally connected, mobile world. I'll just try to remember to copy/refresh/past before posting after a fail.

Comment: I can confirm I had seen this behavior a lot of times (well, I don't need to "disconnect" anything manually. The government does the job perfectly.)  Although I admit I haven't seen it recently.

Comment: @Jeff - testing now...

Comment: I get human verification - a perfectly respectable compromise. My train journey will now involve less swearing. Much obliged.

Comment: @Jeff: I know you use windows, but on most other OS'es you could do `ifconfig lo down`, or some other close variant, depending on the name of the loopback device. However, in windows you can fake it by using the IP of your external card, and then changing the IP midway through the stream... I know you don't need this anymore, but it might be useful for next time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Can someone explain what this is? I read the other post and I didn't understand a thing!

(I googled haiku and learned about it, but what does it have to do with SO?)

Comment: Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan

Comment: If you're ever in Austin, Minnesota, there's this museum...

Comment: I've been there, it's kinda sad.

Comment: Spam, the word, is being used two ways.  **1.** Posts on Stack Overflow that is *spam*.  **2.** Processed and canned meat that originates from Minnesota.

Comment: http://www.spam.com/

Comment: oh, it's an automatic spam detector that's not working? Why won't you tell me? Why are you being so mean?

Comment: Yes, it is a spam trap. Real people occasionally fall in; from what I hear, that applies to regular spam factories, too.

Comment: Spam in one sense helped win WWII.  Spam in the other sense, well, didn't.

Comment: @Juan Manuel: This is not answering the OP's question. You are asking what was asked here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked

Comment: @shog9: close, but not quite haiku.  try this: "if you're ever in / Austin, Minnesota, there's / this great museum"

Comment: On spam:  I love it, I'm having spam spam spam spam spam spam spam baked beans spam spam spam and spam!