# Can't ask, answer, vote, comment, retag any question

Tags: support, spam, haiku

What's this thing when I try answering questions:

> Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan

screenshot:

[alt text http://mathematicsociety.com/images/ScreenshotFirefox.png](http://mathematicsociety.com/images/ScreenshotFirefox.png)

I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509) but I'm not a spam ... I found out something ...

I'm working in a software company and all software developers here got this error and our reputation reduced about 100 points (I had 789 reduced to 669). Reputation isn't important for me ( just as incentive tool ) but I can't answer, vote, comment, retag or even ask any question!

I thought that's because we use the same Internet connection (and spend most of our time in the company), but when I came back home and try to answer questions, I got that message again.

What can I do to re-enable my account and answer questions , put comment, etc?

**P.S:** many hours ago I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032957/combo-control-like-windows-vista/2032971#2032971) question  ... I used the word S...E...X in that thread ... everything happened just after I post that answer !!!

Comment: At least you dropped in the screenshot.

Comment: can't even set a question as my accepted answer ... WHO SHOULD ENABLE MY ACCOUNT ???

Comment: In response to the postscript in your update, does your company filter traffic? Maybe your post triggered a block rule.

Comment: @Anonymous: the OP states that he has the same problem at home, so the problem is not confined to his company's internet connection.

Comment: @Michel: try to email the SO team: `team@stackoverflow.com` (link can also be found at the bottom of every page).

Comment: Maybe your company is so friendly you all upvote each other's posts.

Comment: @random that's not a good reason for disabling my account, upvoting or downvoting a user is not a definition of a "SPAM" ! upvoting isn't that important .... every user can upvote just one time ! my account disabled just after I used word "S ... E ... X" in a thread :( that's the reason

Comment: If that's the reason, Michel, why are you the only one who complains about it? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sex

Comment: I don't care about the reason John ... possible reasons discussed here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked ... What should I do now ? @Stephan202 I emailed to team@stackoverflow.com and waiting for possible responses ...

Comment: @John Smithers  I'm not the only one: Marc Gravell got this error too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32712/overactive-spam-ku http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32796/strange-haiki-after-posting-message etc. Maybe the reason is not about word S*e**X ...

Comment: hope my account re-enabled again ... I'm waiting for that !

Comment: BTW, since you have >200 SO rep, you can get your lost points back by associating your meta / SO accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to try; clear your broswers cache (script in particular). On multiple occasions I have seen (both personally and reported here on meta) problems with dirty cached script versions, which have prevented posting (and on one occasion the moderator screens **looked** like I was actioning things, but not actually doing anything - which was annoying).

The haiku is, I suspect, a red-herring. Your account is not suspended (it would show in red - it isn't subtle), and there is no prejudicial treatment against "sex" (see, I'm still here).

The sudden drop *could* have related to a recalc, but there is nothing in the log (which you get from manual recalcs). I can't see any "spam" penalties (but these are hard to see on questions), so I *assume* it was an automated recalc due to suspect-looking cross-voting (I am not intimate with the exact algorithm, so I can't say for sure).

---

Edit: I hate to be the harbinger of bad news, but for info there 2 accounts (that "share a theme", shall we say) that look **well** along the road to getting eliminated for... *creative* voting. It could well be your co-workers trying to help your account along, but it really isn't in your best interests. Maybe the system already kicked a 3rd, explaining the drop. But this *wouldn't* prevent you accessing the system. We're not bitter.

Comment: that's not cache problem ( I tried in 3 computers and even with my cellphone ) ... but my account re-enabled today ... thank you