# Human verification on all answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, captcha

The last two or three times I answered some question in SO (the last 2-3 hours), I was asked for *Human verification*. Is this a new bug, eventually related to the resolution of [Overactive spam-ku](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32712/overactive-spam-ku)?

It's normal to happen from time to time, but now it was like as it gets triggered on all questions.
Haven't tested... and it's not a big deal.

#### EDIT: Conclusion

It was NOT a bug, It just toke too long to enter the answers and that triggers the bot filter.

Comment: As a counter-point, I have not had any issues with answers in the last few hours, so this is more likely to be something that you are doing to trigger the bot filter.

Comment: Toked too long to enter the answers? I hate it when that happens!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means you've tripped into one of the bot filters.

This can happen if:

- You change IP between loading the page and hitting submit
- You take a long time forming your question
- Your network connection is flaky
- You are going too fast (opening lots of pages very quickly)
- The time between loading the page and hitting submit is very short
- Someone sharing your IP is doing something suspicious (school or work networks)
- You aren't registered and are loading pages in a strange pattern

Comment: OK, it was "You take a long time forming your question" (an answer). I'm sure I stayed long editing the answer... but I didn't think that could not be the cause: normally machines (bots) are faster than humans :-)

Comment: Could you please specifically define the rules with: *a long time*, *too fast* and *very short*? In terms of numbers of course. *A long time* may differ a lot relatively speaking.

Comment: @Carlos - Yeah, it's counter-intuitive, but it turns out spammers sometimes try to work around the "you have to request the page before you can submit the answer" by requesting a lot of pages and caching them, and then posting a lot of answers to them later, or using what essentially amounts to a replay attack, where they use the same page credentials over and over again.

Comment: @Robert - no, I couldn't, I don't know them.  These are reasons I've deduced from my own personal use of SO (and I'm not automating or spamming anything - this is just my normal usage), but I've never measured anything.  In another answer about anti-spam measures, Jeff indicated he wouldn't divulge any details (for obvious reasons) so I doubt you'll find a nice concise list anywhere.

Comment: Ahh, I understand... sad that such procedures are needed,
 but for sure I can live with them (the *captcha* isn't that hard)