# What is this "spam haiku" nonsense all about?

Tags: discussion, haiku

No one is talking
Many of us are clueless
WTF

Comment: -1 because WTF is not 5 syllables.

Comment: @Phosi:  You are so wrong!  Doub-le U T F!  Count 'em!

Comment: @raven: That's not how I pronounce it.

Comment: Further, while "WTF" may be a suitable Kireji, the verse given lacks any discernible kigo.

Comment: Ooooh. I hadn't thought of that. I'd totally un-downvote now if I could.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28electronic%29 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28food%29 - Go figure!

Comment: @Phoshi - Added `haiku` tag. Now unfrozen is your vote. Up-vote if you wish.

Comment: Bah! I un-downvoted, now I can't upvote for some reason. Still, I un-downvoted :P

Comment: This haiku stuff is getting on my nerves. I think my cursing finally got to his blog VM...

Comment: @Phoshi - You only have one chance. Either "undo down-vote" or "reverse to up-vote" before you are "outside the window." Try again after edit.

Comment: If I explain this will someone be angry with me? There seems a convention to avoid answering this question.

Comment: the first rule of haiku club is **do not talk about haiku club**

Comment: Last line could be "One word: WTF"

Comment: Relevant: http://www.systemcomic.com/2008/10/02/the-system-66/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

he looks so confused,
"What are these strange words?" he cries,
answers, he finds none

Answer (score 12):

telemarketers
salesmen, advertisers, bots
`kill -9 "spiced ham"`

Answer (score 12):

give a man a fish
and you feed him for a day.
rather, teach haiku.

Answer (score 10):

Oh Stackoverflow!
Jeff Atwood created it
Jon Skeet answers all

Answer (score 9):

*all converge to read

written courtesies gone cold

somewhere a phone rings*

*fruit falls from the tree

birds have not gone for winter

one careless beetle*

***web in disrepair

spiders go strangely absent

they don't like pressed meat***