# I've had strange output on answer submit :)

Tags: discussion

I've had strange output on answer submit :)

The message was :

> Oh tin of pink meat / I ponder what you may be / Snout or ear or feet?

Screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

Funny :)

Why?

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32789/what-is-this-spam-haiku-nonsense-all-about and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer triggered the **spam** detector — hence the reference to pink meat.

Answer (score 2):

It thinks you are submitting spam.

Comment: Maybe :) Question was: `Our kids don't like the nanny.` My answer was: `No nanny isn't a substitute for parental care.` :)

Comment: Too many smiley faces.