# Captcha not shown with JavaScript turned on which makes things difficult

Tags: bug, status-norepro, captcha

It just happened to me on SU that the captcha was not shown. Neither in Safari nor in Firefox was there any way to show it. There was just that robot guy with the numbers on it. Of course I was thinking this was the captcha – and I desperately searched for a text field where I would have to put all those zeros and ones. (Not that it really thought that that many numbers would *really* be the captcha – but lacking anything else on the page, what else should it have been?)

I then disabled JavaScript and the captcha was shown – however ‘Something Bad Happened!’ was shown. Fortunately this time, when using the back button, the text was still there. So, I tried again. This time no captcha was shown but an empty page with nothing more that the following

```
Cube of cold pinkness / Yellow specks of porcine fat / Give me a spork please
```

How is this not confusing?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked

Comment: Well, seemingly it is. So?

Comment: …I hope that, despite the negative score, someone will see the tiny bug report behind this post and take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked]

Comment: Well, they could say that in a way more understandable for the false positives. I mean the bots surely don’t care what text is shown on that page.