# What the heck is this message I get when I submit a post?

Tags: support, answers, fun, error-message

I've just submitted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987245/c-byte-to-string-to-byte-how-to-do-so) and a stupid message appeared (looks like plain text response from server). I had to go rewrite the answer which caused me to get shot by FGITW. I've submitted the answer using IE8 (I normally use Chrome/Safari. IE just happened to be open. It's the second time I'm seeing this today in IE).

```
Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan
```

Comment: See: [Has Stack Overflow been haiku-hacked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked)

Comment: It is spam haiku. It thinks you are a spammer. Shame on you, Mehrdad.

Comment: I get it on every post in IE. I got it for this meta post too. In fact, I couldn't submit a comment. This is from Chrome.

Comment: @Jon B: Isn't this the hell you were talking about a few hours ago?  :) [So where can I ask developers' questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34221/so-where-can-i-ask-developers-questions)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Do not taunt stackoverflow.

Comment: I still can't comment in IE. The spam heuristics are really bad. Wait a minute... didn't Google sponsor SO. Is this a coincidence? :)

Comment: Jeff, at least change that to a country song. I'm depressed.

Comment: Mehrdad, there is something DEEPLY wrong with your IE configuration.

Comment: Jeff, I believe you're right. Nothing else makes sense. Will investigate.

Comment: Country song? Ok, try this: "Everything goes wrong / Country and western haikus / Help me share the pain."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haikus are the worst.
I made this in ten seconds.
It is terrible.