# Finally reached edit ability on SO; life feels oddly unsatisfying and empty

Tags: discussion, reputation

I noticed today that I was really close to reaching the magic 2000 rep benchmark.  Because of this I spent my entire day scouring the site for questions.  It also seemed to be the one day where everything was moving slowly.

Finally, at 1:30 AM local time, I passed the mark.  And I didn't receive any of that personal satisfaction that I had strove so hard to find.  I didn't find that warm fuzzy feeling.  My life feels oddly unsatisfying and empty and perhaps even lonely, despite having actual friends.

Sitting here I am granted with the hollow ability to edit other posts, an ability which I have spent my all my time and energy that life had given me in order to accomplish.  And now...everything feels so...empty.

Is this expected behavior?  Or should I file a bug report or a feature request?

Comment: This is human nature. We want something really hard, then we get surprised at how little the "happiness" lasts, and in some cases, we get surprised at the lack of "happiness". Things we want are always better than what we have. What we want is always really good and we really want, once we have it, it can't be all that good anymore, right, because even we got it! I would check the Area 51 website for a psychology proposal, and ask this there. I am sure they will have plenty to say to you  :)  Congratulations, by the way!

Comment: I felt like that until i got my first girlfriend. After a while i still felt unsatisfied. So i turned to programming, now i have no friends as well. You just can't win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fulfillment is a difficult goal to algorithmically achieve.

But ultimately, no. This is not the expected behaviour, and because the application is working correctly, I can only assume the faulty device is you.

If you do not find nirvana when your rep ticks past 2000, then you have serious deficiencies. That would be like not enjoying waffles, or not weeping when you hear a unicorn's laughter. These are the simple joys of life that every well adjusted human being cannot help but enjoy

I know that when I first past 2000 points, a rapturous climactic release took hold of me, and caused a significant disruption to the board meeting I was in.

I think your only recourse is to get back to work, get your rep past 3000 and see if you feel fulfilled then.

Comment: So the application is exhibiting expected behavior, but the client (myself) is not?  So to whom should I file the bug report?  I hope they use Jira.

Comment: @Justin You should file a bug report to your manufacturer.

Comment: so you are telling me that after you got 2k rep you didn't almost immediately start thinking about the next threshold reputation value you could achieve to release a feature? We always want more. Justin isn't faulty: this is a feature purposely included in all humans. We all have it, you included. If not, then the faulty device is actually you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, it's boring .. that is, **until you begin editing everyone else's posts to liven them up with *hilarious* ASCII art!** *

<sub>* do not actually do this</sub>

Comment: *do not actually do this* - well no, he can't, since you specified **hilarious** ASCII art.

Comment: or [into a haiku](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked)?

Comment: re-writing everyone else's questions in haiku form is now my new purpose in life.

Comment: @Justin L: Definitely a worthy cause.