# Some security features cause users with low reputation to lose the question content they just typed

Tags: bug, asking-questions, spam, draft

I just lost an hour worth of time carefully typing this question (with some hyperlinks in it) to end up on a page saying a bullshit phrase like "I wonder what thou art, sprout or bean or.....". This page does not provide any possibility to go back to your question. After clicking back in the browser I lost all that work. Honestly, "bad security is worse than no security".

Reproduce:

1. post an article with a low rep account with some links and a new tag.
2. You will be asked to fill out a captcha
3. you will return to you question with 2 error messages, one for the links, and one for the tags (as a side note, these are two issues that could easily be resolved without further user interaction).
4. Remove the new tag, but leave the links.
5. Push publish again to see a grey page with just one phrase in old english.

I am no doubt not a very humorous person, but honestly I have better things to do than write two times the same thing.

There is a lot to say about overzealous policing as well, but I have no time for that.

I seriously considered abandoning trying to secure my application because asking a question on stackexchange was my last resort after days of searching, and my time is really running out.

On top of that I am not even capable of typing the same thing twice. BLAH! Bad user experience.

If you seriously want to keep users who already filled out a captcha from posting a question with links in it, at least make sure they don't lose their work and can "break" the links before they post.

Comment: sounds like you had JavaScript disabled? because we auto-save drafts, etc, but if you hit that text, you triggered a *lot* of filters.

Comment: I recoverd the first two paragraphs out of 8 or so... The autosave definitely is a good thing, but appearantly it doesn't fire when you click publish, and seemingly not very frequently otherwise either.

Comment: did you, or did you not, have JavaScript disabled or NoScript or anything like that?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked

Comment: I do have noscript, set to globally allow scripts, and I did have some part of the post that has been saved by autosave, however at that one time when you don't need ajax, namely when I clicked the publish button, no autosave was made.

Comment: @Jeff — Having JavaScript turned off is part of the Universal Declaration of Rights of the Internet User — which I have just invented.