# Could not submit answer on SO because name missing?

Tags: bug

I was just prompted to enter my name and email when answering a question on SO:

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> name and email are missing

Then, when I tried to just post the answer again without entering data, I got this:

> Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan

URL bar shows: [Why is malloc really non-deterministic? (Linux/Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251639/answer/submit)

I have been logged into SO answering questions successfully all morning.

What's up with that?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked

Comment: Pretty funny :-)

Comment: Try logging out and back in, and clearing your cookies if that doesn't work.

Comment: do you have javascript disabled, or otherwise unusual browser defaults?

Comment: When you say "when I tried to just post the answer again **without entering data**", do you mean that there were input fields on the page for your name, email, and website, below the main textarea?  You can see these input fields when looking at a question in incognito mode...

Comment: I'm just checking that you were indeed logged in, as the code that does that particular check only runs for anonymous users.