# Was the robot detector upgraded today? SO keeps checking if I'm real

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)

Most workdays, I have SO open all day in the background and take time now and then to answer questions.  Today was no different (no particular deviation from the usual pattern).

Today, the robot heuristics thought I was not real

[Could not submit answer on SO because name missing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138051/could-not-submit-answer-on-so-because-name-missing)

Since then I have been prompted to enter Captcha several times (the page with the robot picture).

If there was an update to the heuristics today, the update might be tuned a little too restrictive.  If there was no update, I guess I'm just getting unlucky today or something.

Comment: Nice try, robot.

Comment: Beep.  Beep.  Beep.

Comment: 30,000 reputation? Obviously the robot detection isn't good enough! :o

Comment: What if you were abducted in your sleep and your mind was copied into a machine like a computer into a VM? What if that happened to *all of us*? And Stack Overflow is the only thing in the universe that can tell us the truth? Crap, that's scary.

Comment: ASSIMILATE. ASSIMILATE.

Comment: @AakashM: Your comment is going to be incomprehensible when Pekka changes his name again.