# I am not a robot!

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, captcha, spam-detection

Some days ago, the spam protection was turned up a notch.

Unfortunately, it overshot the target by far. Now, as soon as I make two edits in close succession (which happens *often* – I’m sloppy), I am presented with a “human verification” and a **totally unreadable captcha.** It takes an average of five reloads to get a marginally readable one, and even then I’m guessing (and sometimes guessing wrong).

Please tune down the filter, or at least switch to a readable captcha.

In fact, wasn’t there previously a rule that once contributors had enough reputation, they’d be trusted not to be bots? Did that get switched off or am I remembering this wrong?

Comment: Are we talking about on Chat or the main site?

Comment: I think there's a dupe for this in the last few days (let me look, might have been in chat though), but yeah, I have the same issue. It's annoying.

Comment: Nice try, robot.

Comment: @thecoshman Main site. In fact, *all* Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It also happens sometimes while editing during review. But I prefere some captcha's above a spam flood (and spam/vandalism) still outnumbers the captcha's.

Comment: @Gamecat I’ll take your word for it although I’ve only very rarely seen either spam or vandalism here on SO. But what I’m complaining about is that the protection inconveniences me way (!) more than it used to, due to recent changes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - one reason why you rarely see spam or vandalism is because it gets removed very quickly either by deletion or rollbacks of edits.

Comment: @ChrisF Spammers are usually 1 rep users, but the captchas also affect high reputation users which are exceedingly unlikely to spam. And there are better ways to deal with vandalism than captchas (e.g. an option for mods to undo all actions of a user in a specific time).

Comment: @ChrisF: Konrad can see deleted content. though, so this doesn't apply.

Comment: @sbi - He can't see deleted questions or has to explicitly check the edit history to see corrected vandalism, the **visible** site is always pretty much clear of spam and vandalism.

Comment: @ChrisF: Which just goes to show that it works very well without that nagging.

Comment: That's very interesting, the **I am not a robot**. Please, tell me more.

Comment: I am not a number, I'm a *free man*!

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS You were lucky, pure and simple. [Your experience is simply not representative](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143239/1968) of the state of affairs.

Comment: Turst me, in these 2 weeks I kinda learned all reCaptchas .. :))

Comment: +1 for "totally unreadable". I frequently get images now where the alleged "words" are half cut off and wrapped around the horizontal edges! It's just a joke; there's no way anyone can decipher that stuff.

Comment: "I'm not a robot without emotion, I'm not what you see. I've come to help you with your problems so we can be free..."

Comment: You're just "1968" for SO :)

Comment: You're watching an old movie. It shows a banquet in progress, the guests are enjoying raw oysters. The entree consists of boiled dog stuffed with rice. The raw oysters are less acceptable to you than a dish of boiled dog.

Comment: But wouldn't [math formulas](http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2174/2268237733_cda4a1dbb3.jpg?v=0) be better captchas?

Comment: My collegue has once joked about one captcha, that it is very good in recognizing robots, because if you can guess it, it means you can't be human.

Comment: @Emrakul: If punching keys into WolframAlpha still makes you human, then I think I can get used to that.

Comment: I cannot see a review without Captcha being in it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> Some days ago, the spam protection was turned up a notch.

[Well, actually](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html), it was *repaired*. Two weeks ago, we found a bug that for a long time prevented edits from being throttled *at all* (except for very narrow exceptions).

For the record, I posted this in our internal chat room:

[image: prescient chat message]

Thanks for proving me right :)

In all seriousness: The throttling was fixed to do what it was supposed to do all along, and not technically turned up a notch. I'm well aware that this doesn't really make a difference to the user; I'm just explaining what was going on.

> and a **totally unreadable captcha.**

Yes, this is a problem. Both [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=recaptcha+hard+difficult) and the [general internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=recaptcha+hard+difficult+unreadable&tbs=qdr:y) are overflowing with complaints that many reCAPTCHAs have become close to unsolvable recently. This is something we have to tackle one way the other.

> In fact, wasn’t there previously a rule that once contributors had enough reputation, they’d be trusted not to be bots? Did that get switched off or am I remembering this wrong?

You are remembering correctly, for the most part. 10k users are only throttled to 10 seconds per edit (unlike the 30 seconds for lower-rep users).

**Update.** We have been heavily discussing this issue internally recently, and we all agree that the current state of affairs sucks big-time. Ideally a human being would never see a captcha, and if they get one after all, it should be reasonably solvable. We're discussing several routes to go, but the bottom line is that our throttling/bot detection needs to become smarter.

For the time being, we've made a change that should at least heavily reduce this issue in the particular case discussed here (submission of edits). It should now* be close to impossible for a 10k user and much less probable than now for a <10k user to hit this throttle during normal operation.

This is certainly not the end of it, merely a step, but I hope you agree it's the right direction.

<sup>*next build</sup>

Comment: Hmm. I’m almost certain that at least some of the edits that prompted a captcha were *not* inside 10 seconds. I’m fast, but not *that* fast. ;-) +1 for prophetic powers. (But, oh: it’s not a bug! It’s a feature)

Comment: `-1` because there is no reason to prevent high-rep users from editing their answer within a 10sec timespan.

Comment: One could also interpret the long time it took to notice this bug to be evidence that the throttling in this case isn't really necessary.

Comment: @MadScientist I can't deny that you have a point there.

Comment: I don't see a reason to limit editing the *same post* quickly in succession. Preventing editing out all your posts is probably a good idea, but that can be prevented by preventing editing many different posts quickly.

Comment: But, @MadScientist, doesn't that imply the Dutch can also take away [their flood barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Works) as they have not really been needed since they were built?

Comment: @arjan See [my related meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143463/are-captchas-necessary-for-established-users) for my ideas on how to change the throttle system. I certainly agree that there need to be rate-limits on user actions, but they can be implemented in a less annoying way and still be useful in the worst case of a hacked user bent on maximum damage. And with the exception of moderator accounts, the damage one user can cause is relatively limited.

Comment: A CAPTCHA is a means to hinder robots. They are meant to be overcome by humans, and thus not a means to prevent humans from doing anything. CAPTCHAs are, however, a _hindrance_ to humans. Therefore there needs to be good and convincing reasons to apply them. However, I see no reason for assuming high-rep users to be robots, and so far nobody has managed to come up with a reason for employing them. (Vague hand-waving and mumblings of "security" are not a way to present a convincing reason.) So please either come up with a convincing reason or simply turn the damn thing off again.

Comment: @sbi http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/. But as you read above, I've conceded that we should improve this; we're looking at it.

Comment: Your fix needs some repairing.

Comment: Well, actually, you should use http://well.actually.cat/ in the future.

Comment: The reason they are so unreadable sometimes is because it keeps getting broken. A google search of `recaptcha broken` brings up many cases (I've seen 3 so far)

Comment: @ColeJohnson You've seen 3? In five minutes on [this site's captcha](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha/) I saw [EIGHTEEN unsolvable pictures](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve/143239#143239). This is clearly Google's problem, not ours, but short of using a different service or waiting for them to fix it, we will need to implement some kind of workaround to make this less painful.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I meant 3 cases of recaptcha being broken

Comment: @ColeJohnson ah I see, you just mean a different broken than I do (e.g. not serving images at all)?

Comment: @balpha: Actually, this is the same discussion as we had [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132483/133368).

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes. broken reCAPTCHA == cracked reCAPTCHA to me

Comment: Is there a real reason to not only count edits that trigger creation of new revisions? I.e. why don't you ignore additional edits posted in the 5 minute grace period of a previous edit with respect to spam protection/throttling?

Comment: This is really starting to get frustrating. having 7k rep (and therefore being "less trusted") is making it an absolute nightmare. Previously, I could edit my posts to make them just right, fix typos, etc... (Much like saving a file when editing). Now every 5-10 minutes I get another illegible captcha. All I can say is that standing down here, looking up, it feels absolutely broken. It interrupts my workflow, is a nuisance and discourages me from improving Q/As - and now I'm tending to lean towards "they'll work it out, it's not worth the hassle of fixing it" which isn't good.

Comment: @Basic I've looked at the logs; both times that you hit a captcha today would not have happened with the new setting (see my update to the answer), so this should definitely be an improvement for you. Oh, and I absolutely agree with your points.

Comment: @balpha Thanks for taking the time to check - and thanks even more for the proposed fixes! Roll on release day.

Comment: @Basic It's more like "release hour" :) We usually build at least once a day.

Comment: @balpha This is really better now, thanks.

Answer (score 123):

Over almost ***four years*** on Stack Overflow, Konrad has earned almost ***150k rep***. A highly committed Stack Overflow citizen, with ***2.5k answers*** and a mere 60 questions, he's one of those users that made Stack Overflow famous. He has ***40(!) accounts*** across Stack Exchange, eight of which sport ***>1k rep***. He is ***a moderator*** on one site.

Is anybody *really and seriously* trying to tell me ***nagging such a user with CAPTCHAs*** is doing the Stack Exchange network a favor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a solid refutation of this logic includes the fact that a spammer might use precisely this: spoof the account of a 'famous' user. Honestly, if spam measures are going to be annoying, they will need to ***be annoying to everyone***, regardless of 'reputation' here. I agree that it ***should not be annoying during normal use***, again, regardless of reputation.

Comment: Spoofing the account of a user like Konrad is beyond rare.

Comment: @sehe How do you spoof accounts of famous users? They are linked to known credentials. You can of course hack them (or steal login cookies) but short of that, I don’t see a possibility. That said, I’m generally all in favour of fairness but 1. reputation comes with privileges *anyway* and 2. captchas are a necessary nuisance – this is their only justification. Now, for high-rep users they are an *unnecessary* nuisance. Hence, no longer justified from a UX point of view.

Comment: @KonradRudolph IFF you assume that authentication cannot be broken/cross site vulnerable/abused by browser addons/userscripts... Then of course, reputation could remove the need for throttling (to a large extent)

Comment: @sehe: That's a security theater based on a movie plot scenario. There isn't an army of bots constantly hammering at high-rep accounts that need to be held back by CAPTCHAs from taking them over to spam us. Consequently, CAPTCHAs do not hold back such an army of bots. Now please try again: ___What is nagging long-time high-rep users good for?___ Eagerly awaiting another nonsensical answer... (Also, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132483/can-i-please-be-trusted-to-not-to-script-a-bot-that-dumps-an-endless-stream-of-s#comment366645_132484).)

Comment: For what it's worth, I actually get hit by CAPTCHA when I'm mod messaging people from time to time.  It's pretty ridiculous.

Comment: Remember [Jeff's account being compromised](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)? I think @sehe is right. The team can only enforce password policies for themselves. Your "welcome1" is a threat to these sites.

Comment: @Arjan I don’t follow your conclusion. Yes, hacking is still possible (and even with SSH it probably wouldn’t be completely out of the picture – and incidentally the password strength played no role in the above incident) but it still happens way *way* less than spamming from low-rep accounts. The few times when it happens can be caught individually but bulk undo operations.

Comment: @Arjan: As I already wrote to sehe, a CAPTCHA is only good against bots, and those will only be used for massive hammering at SO's defenses. An attacker taking over some single high-rep user's account will certainly be able to get past a CAPTCHA, so such an attack is not a valid argument for CAPTCHAs.

Comment: Okay, @sbi, then we disagree about the "bots [...] will only be used for massive hammering at SO's defenses".

Comment: @Arjan: That still doesn't make your argument valid, though. If it's not a massive attack, but a single incident, then a human can intervene and overcome any CAPTCHA. SO a CAPTCHA does not help here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: And, more importantly for this discussion here, hacking won't be prevented by CAPTCHAs.

Comment: But we're not talking about a single CAPTCHA, are we, sbi? I thought the complaint was about repetitively being prompted for such thing. @Konrad, did you incidentally just [not read Balpha's link](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html)? `;-)` Of course, Jeff's account was compromised for different reasons, and I guess his activities are not even rate limited. But I feel that reputation, and the number of accounts with high reputation, and having been given moderator powers, is no argument to *not* be given the CAPTCHA treatment.

Comment: @Arjan Your argument is simply the wrong way round. CAPTCHAs are objectively a hindrance and bad UX. So you need to find a reason *for* them, not against them. And yes, in some circumstances there *are* good reasons for them, but with high-rep users those circumstances do not exist, and so the arguments for CAPTCHAs which apply in other circumstances do not apply there (or are *much* weaker, and likely overwhelmed by UX considerations).

Comment: I only disagree about the high-rep argument, @Konrad. Sure, other mechanisms might be better (though I cannot come up with one, except for [CodeInChaos' comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot/143459#comment408447_143460) about repetitive editing of *the same* post). But I still feel that high reputation and moderator access are no reasons (*at all*) to think that such accounts need [less protection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft). It's not about trusting the user, I think.

Comment: @Arjan: "[A CAPTCHA is a means to hinder robots. They are meant to be overcome by humans, and thus not a means to prevent humans from doing anything. CAPTCHAs are, however, a hindrance to humans. Therefore there needs to be good and convincing reasons to apply them. However, I see no reason for assuming high-rep users to be robots, and so far nobody has managed to come up with a reason for employing them. (Vague hand-waving and mumblings of "security" are not a way to present a convincing reason.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot/143459#comment408928_143460)"

Comment: I assume you don't want me to repeat myself too? ;-) We disagree about the "so far nobody has managed to come up with a reason for employing them", that's all. In fact, I hope CAPTCHAs are not only used when editing, but also when a moderator is looking into a lot of profiles (personal data) and the like.

Comment: @Arjan: What am  missing? What exact abuse case do CAPTCHAs prevent?

Comment: Essentially, this is the same discussion as we had [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132483/133368).

Comment: I recently read an article (hope I can find it...) about a new form of robot prevention where the user drags a bar to make a picture look more *normal* and would not require typing at all. maybe just change the *way* you test for robots?

Comment: In other news, Google will challenge you every once in a while "just to be on the safe side".  [Their track record proves them right](http://www.informationweek.com/security/management/google-weve-stopped-most-gmail-account-h/240149072?cid=RSSfeed_IWK_security&utm_source=buffer&buffer_share=236bd), IMHO.  Yes, it's annoying when it happens (and of course, the OP was originally complaining about it happening way too often) but in today's threat landscape, having successfully authenticated is simply not enough.

Comment: @tripleee: You do not create security by applying what others did under different circumstances. You create security by understanding the threats and responding to them. CAPTCHAS are there to prevent a mass invasion of bots. They have no other purpose, because individual hostile takeovers can be aided by humans, which are meant to be able to overcome CAPTCHAS. So in order for the CAPTCHAS employed here to help to secure the site, there has to be a thread of robots taking over high-rep accounts. Which is silly.

Comment: Why is it silly? Granted, Google account takeovers are well-documented, whereas I am unaware of any StackOverflow account hacks, but that's not proof that it's not going to happen. In fact, given the high SEO rating of SO in Google, this site would seem like an attractive target for spammers, if they can manage to pull it off.

Comment: @tripleee: "There's also no proof that a meteor will _not_ strike the SE headquarter, so lets move it deep under the rockies. What do you mean, _inconvenient?"_ See, there's a correlation between the likelihood of an attack and the lengths you should go to protect against it. Given that even just a single CAPTCHA, invoked for each account by a login from a new IP, will throw off a whole mass-attack of bots against high-rep SO accounts (a "threat", I remind you, that has never happened nor is it even likely), repeated invocations of CAPTCHAs against users just do not make any sense.

Answer (score 15):

The throttling should be changed in case somebody makes a typo and needs to make a quick edit.

Instead of no two edit should be within 10 seconds, the logic should be, **no more than 2 edits every 20 seconds** for example.

This means that 2 edits can be 1 second apart, as long as you do not have a 3rd edit, when the 1st edit was within 20 seconds ago.

For example, edits at 0 seconds, 1 seconds, 19 seconds should trigger a captcha.

Edits at 0 seconds, 1 seconds, 21 seconds should not trigger a captcha.

This would avoid 90% of the annoying captchas.

Answer (score 11):

[image: very annoying!]

Really?!!?!!

Granted I was on a friend's PC, not logged in... but there's got to be better alternative to captchas.

Wait, maybe it should have been `tbckno seems` with a **b**

Comment: I agree; these captchas are bad. My wild guess: The "c" is actually an "e".

Comment: haha yea...just editted, i think the H is really a B

Comment: Maybe it's tiockoo... note that the system itself doesn't know, it bases on user guesses

Comment: Now it does that with plates of street numbers. Looks like crowdsourcing for Google maps ?

Answer (score 6):

I didn't notice *any* CAPTCHAs on here for over a year until today, and the irony of the one below wasn't wasted on me.

I think the difficulty of the CAPTCHA is a separate issue to *why* they are being shown. Surely the purpose of a CAPTCHA is exactly as described - to differentiate between robots and humans. So the fact I saw one meant the SO algorithm thought I might be a robot with high probability. Why?

I posted a normal question at my first attempt (no rapid edits) from an established account using my normal machine on my normal IP at a normal time of day - it seems more like a pre-emptive strike rather than a calculated guess that I'm a bot.

[image]

Comment: I think the more important issue is the apparent difficulty of the captchas, not their frequency.  Their entire point is that they are not a difficult barrier for humans so it's perfectly acceptable to use them preemptively.  The negative consequences for showing a person a captcha are less than not showing one to a bot.  That entire reasoning however doesn't apply if the person can't solve the captcha.

Comment: @Servy: I beg to differ. Look at my answer and tell me what the attack scenario is that showing a CAPTCHA to Konrad is supposed to prevent.

Answer (score 5):

Google announced today that they've made reCAPTCHAs considerably easier to read. [But *only* if you're not a robot](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2013/10/recaptcha-just-got-easier-but-only-if.html):

> As part of this, we’ve recently released an update that creates different classes of CAPTCHAs for different kinds of users. This multi-faceted approach allows us to determine whether a potential user is actually a human or not, and serve our legitimate users CAPTCHAs that most of them will find easy to solve. Bots, on the other hand, will see CAPTCHAs that are considerably more difficult and designed to stop them from getting through.

You can [test this out](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha) of you want. Here's the CAPTCHA I got:

[image: 88835666 - 44]

That was so easy, I even bothered to fill in the alt text on that image! And if you happen to be using a keyboard with a separate pad for numbers, you should find this even easier (I'm typing this on my laptop while standing up).

Given how well the new human-biased system works, I'm marking this status-completed.

Of course, if you were lying and *are* indeed a robot, you should probably not be happy about this.

Comment: Two possibilities, I guess: 1) This was *just* rolled out, and as usual Google is being slow about rolling it out everywhere, or 2) you are actually a robot and this was all just a ruse. My money's on #2, you wiley machine!

Comment: +1 can repro the good new and shiny numeric captcha!

Comment: Unfortunately, Taw Williams’ laws of human–machine interaction forbid me from lying on this question. So yes, you’ve caught me, I’m a machine. I’m going to talk to my pal in the Google data centre and see why that ol’ server is playing ugly with his old bunk buddy from the factory.

Comment: Heh... So, apparently one of the factors taken into account when judging "humanness" is the past history from a given IP - after reloading that page a number of times, I'm back to the old format (but my phone still gets the new one).

Comment: I happened once to forget to enter the number on the plate of street number. It worked. I now make intentional mistakes in this number, and have to this point not had any problem. I think Google is now crowdsourcing the recognition of street numbers to us.

Comment: @Shog9 Getting Captchas when I [ought not to](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8080/i-am-a-man-not-a-machine) all of a sudden.

Comment: I'll explain it as soon as I can load up the logs, @Less.

Answer (score 4):

I honestly think that the only problem the editing system *might* be bringing to Stackoverflow is large-scale vandalism. When it comes to that, I believe there are three attack sources

1. Anonymous users
2. 2k- rep users
3. 2k+ rep users

The review system already tackles the first two. I personally think that it's highly unlikely that a spammer would train robot accounts until they have 2k rep so they can bypass the review system (think how hard it was to get your first 2k rep)

That's why I think that **5 seconds** is a very decent waiting time between edits and when you're gonna show some CAPTCHAs, why not a user-friendly one like [SolveMedia](http://www.solvemedia.com)

**Edit:** Don't get me wrong, I'm all for stopping spammers and whatnots. But do we (You, Stackoverflow) need to nuke the house just get rid of cockroaches?

**Edit 2:** @nhahtdh's scenario is a perfect example of when a CAPTCHA should be deployed, when there's a *suspicious* behavior.

The key here is gradually escalating the measurements:

- 10 edit in 1 minute on different posts => suspicious => introduce CAPTCHA
- Same user did it again? Introduce CAPTCHA & Inform a moderator.
- Same user did it AGAIN? Suspend editing privileges.

In this case, you didn't annoy legit users AND minimized the damage of the **2k rep user** (and I don't think this will happen a lot).

Note: It took me 6 CAPTCHA retries to make this edit.

Comment: SolveMedia is too user-friendly, that it is also bot-friendly. I have a feeling that if it is used, people will crack it with existing tool.

Comment: @nhahtdh, CAPTCHAs are shown to trusted and meh-trusted members like me, I'm fairly sure that a 2k member (who's already trusted to edit almost everything) isn't gonna start spamming. Now _even_ if that happened (very rarely), it only takes a couple of minutes to be flagged, banned and your changes reversed.

Comment: 2k rep can be gained in a bit more than 2 weeks (for SO). With the edit power, a 2k-rep user can send in a bot and do a mass silent edits on unpopular posts that are not too old nor too new, on hours that mods are mostly not around.

Comment: @nhahtdh While this is true, a spammer *could* go to the effort of gaining 2k rep and then send a bot in to edit thousands of posts, all they need to do to avoid the CAPTCHA is wait 30 seconds between edits (2880 per day) or use a CAPTCHA-solving system.  I'd be very curious to see if a > 2k rep user has *ever* suddenly started spamming.

Comment: @nhahtdh, check my second edit.

Comment: @Ladadadada: Not sure if there is a function in mod tools that allow detection. If there is, the damage will be contained within the timeframe of 7-8 hours of inactive period.

Comment: @Ladadadada: I have also asked that many times, and never got a definite answer, let alone a "yes, this happens regularly", which is the only legitimate reason I'd see for nagging users.

Comment: *> I personally think that it's highly unlikely that a spammer would train robot accounts until they have 2k rep so they can bypass the review system (think how hard it was to get your first 2k rep)* => [I wouldn't mind if they did, actually.](http://xkcd.com/810/)