# Too much spam validation?

Tags: support, spam, captcha

If I start answering in the morning, everything is fine and I can just answer the questions without any delay. But at the end of my day I get more and more "spam checks" which want to validate that I am not a computer.

I can appreciate the check, but to check me out every other question feels like... spam :)

What am I doing wrong? Is there something in my behavior that triggers this?

(Also, this happens at the same time my editor buttons are missing).

Comment: Are you on a connection that regularly switches IP address?

Comment: Nope. My internet provider provides me with a fixed IP address.

Comment: You also see the captcha if you are posting new answers within 30 seconds.

Comment: Ah.. what about two edits in 30 seconds?

Comment: Just added an answer again. Before that I was in the shows. Believe, my showers take longer than 30 seconds :)

Comment: @MartinMulder yup, you will get the captcha if you multiple edits within a short window... I don't remember the exact criteria to trigger it though.

Comment: @MartinMulder [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143460/182513) confirms that more than 1 edit per 30 seconds will trigger CAPTCHA

Comment: @psubsee2003: Thanks! But I do not work that fast. As I just mentioned 5 minutes ago: I got the same check after I hit the shower...

Comment: Which is why I didn't make it an answer. :-)  I was specifically replying to your `what about two edits in 30 seconds` comment.

Comment: You turn into a robot as the day goes on.

Comment: Are you using any userscripts/greasemonkey scripts/etc that might interfere with regular javascript operation?