# Captcha is impossible to solve, worse than anytime before

Tags: bug, captcha

After pasting the answer from clipboard, I was welcomed with captcha to prove I'm a human. It wasn't as easy as I thought:

[image]

Not correct words? Are you kidding?

It seems people have **some** problems with captcha in the past, like here: [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)

However, now captchas are much much worse. Those old ones were a children play compared to that! And in place of old bug we have a new one, much worse!

I have **refreshed the image like mad** about 30 times, about 10 times I've tried to guess before succeeding. Each time I've got similar gibberish!

Please fix that. Choose other provider if needed, because that below even doesn't look like any English words.

Comment: jultryc rtylngu -- I don't see what's so hard about it, and the poor resolution of your image makes it harder that it would be when it's real.

Comment: PROVE YOU ARE AN UBERMENSCH

Comment: Not saying that this is a great solution, but there is a refresh button next to the text box which will give you a new captcha.

Comment: @Servy - Hmm, I dunno. My eyes have trouble with that "jultryc " especially

Comment: The poor quality of the screenshot makes it tougher than it would normally be, as I said before.

Comment: Jeff, Please fix that !

Comment: Jeff works at Google now?

Comment: @StevenV oh, I've forgotten to write I've tried about 30 times, each time getting similar gibberish

Comment: Nice try, robot.

Comment: @Servy what is "jultryc rtylngu"? Google search doesn't give any result except your comment ^^

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Since when do captchas need to be real words?  Using real words makes it a lot easier for robots; it means they only need to figure out a small subset of the letters and then match it against dictionaries.

Comment: Did you try listening to the audio version?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot audio was not an option when I've got that captcha

Comment: OP's username is also an impossible CAPTCHA.

Comment: It's not *impossible* to solve, most image recognition algorithms have grown pretty good at it, just get one of these scripts and have it solve all your captchas. Boom, problem solved.

Comment: @Leeor as my collegue once said, if you can solve it, it means you're a robot

Comment: Odd, it used to be two numbers, now after cache clearing I get what you posted as well. Looks like a change on Google's side.

Comment: @djechlin first 'odd' character means 'boy' and the last means 'happy'. I thought it's obvious :P

Answer (score -1):

Refresh the Captcha (the top button on the right that resembles a Yin-Yang sign) until you get one you can easily read.  As image-recognition software becomes more complex, allowing unscrupulous people the ability to auto-fill Captchas, new Captchas need to be created to thwart those gains.  It's just the nature of the beast.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to write I've refreshed a lot and each time I've got the similar gibberish. It wasn't the single accident. Refresh doesn't help anymore...