# Replacing reCAPTCHA

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, captcha, accessibility, spam-detection

I, like most SE users, am occasionally presented with a CAPTCHA to prove I'm human for one of any number of reasons. At the time of this writing there are [247 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=captcha+is%3Aquestion) and [342 answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=captcha+is%3Aanswer) on Meta regarding CAPTCHAs and such questions often appear on the Community Bulletin (one appeared today which is what prompted this request). If I could search by emotion, I'm guessing the majority would be tagged [angry](/questions/tagged/angry).

On Monday, Google announced that [an algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6082v4) they have developed can solve reCAPTCHA with a 99.8% success rate. Searching around for [studies](http://www.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/burszstein_2010_captcha.pdf) indicating human solve success rate all indicate percentages less than that (for audio CAPTCHAs *much* less than that). This is no longer a valid method for determining if a user is human.

The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143460/196158) to the highest rated Meta question on CAPTCHAs indicated that the SE staff were "heavily discussing this issue" and "agree that the current state of affairs sucks big-time" back in August 2012. Considering the advancement of a computer's ability to solve CAPTCHAs since then, I think it's about time for an alternative.

I'm not claiming to have a definitive answer but suggestions are, of course, welcome.

And I understand that polishing the meta split is probably priority right now, but can we at least get this on the docket?

Comment: This would just mean that someone controlling a bot would need to log the bot in manually, before it went off botting.  That's not really much of a deterrent at stopping what this is designed to stop.

Comment: @Servy As I said, I don't claim to have a solution. Just that the current system is no longer valid. It is easier for a computer to solve a CAPTCHA than a human.

Comment: Until there is significant evidence that captchas are routinely circumvented causing an influx of crap, I'm not sure a whole lot needs to happen.

Comment: @Bart But what about the inconvenience to actual humans who routinely complain of the difficulty?

Comment: Hang around on Meta for a while. We routinely complain about a lot of things. ;)

Comment: Besides, at this point aren't some spammers using actual meatbags for their nefarious purposes?

Comment: The computer for which it's easier is a computer by the very maintainers of reCAPTCHA ...

Comment: Would be interesting to see how many attempts and the precentange that are stoped by captha stop at time of submission.

Answer (score 6):

Captchas' primary function is to serve as a deterrent.

Practically since their creation, there have always been bots out there capable of solving captchas, and there always will be. Even if a bot can solve 20% of captchas, it can just refresh until it gets one that it sees.

The real purpose, though, is to make it inordinately difficult to write code for. Implementing a captcha-solver isn't fun, and people have better things to do with their time than get around the auto-edit checks.

That's why captchas are still effective. It doesn't matter that people *can* break it - it's still just as effective a deterrent as it has been. Nobody wants to bother for something like suggested edits.

Comment: The problem is that when captcha's give human users more of a problem then they give bot's which means they go against the purpose of making it harder for a bot to post then a real human.

Comment: @Joe Not really - someone still has to invest a lot of time writing and implementing bots, and let's be honest, who's going to bother for suggested edits? That's the real point: it's not supposed to be hard, it's supposed to be a deterrent.

Comment: From my understanding when people create a bot to break captcha the bot will work on thousands of sites not just an individual site. Maybe I am wrong about how the SE network handles captcha but I wouldn't assume they have developed a captcha system that would be different enough from others out there that a general bot can't break it.

Comment: That is true, and as a result, SE need only deal with a handful of people.